# Google Sheets - Trying to create a SUM of earnings per MONTH & per YEAR

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm new to all excel google sheet and I was tasked to creat a sheet in which i have a tab/sheet called "Payments" where I record payments from jobs along with other info like date.
I want to create another tab called "Statistics" where I want to `SUM` all earnings per specific month that is seperate for each year.

I am currently trying to use `=ArrayFormula(SUMIF(MONTH(Payments!E2:E500)&YEAR(Payments!F2:F500),"="&MONTH("April")&YEAR("2023"),Payments!H2:H500))`, but not sure why this doesn't work out.

Can you please help?

Link to the [sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1gORd-S0uEqRuzP3VX1-F_EVu8ue8IPrwdIcSL4Sg8ks/edit#gid=1063461587)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With MakeArray you can navigate through your headers with the help of index and the coordinates. And I used LAMBDA and BYCOL for the totals:

```
=LAMBDA(arr,{arr;BYCOL(arr,LAMBDA(each,SUM(each)))})(MAKEARRAY(12,COUNTA(B1:G1),LAMBDA(r,c,SUMIFS(Payments!H2:H500,Payments!E2:E500,INDEX(A2:A13,R),Payments!F2:F500,INDEX(B1:G1,c)))))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here's something else you can try (in B2):

```
=ArrayFormula(LAMBDA(table,{table;BYCOL(table,LAMBDA(col,SUM(col)))})(SUMIF(Payments!E2:E&Payments!F2:F,A2:A13&B1:F1,Payments!H2:H)))
```